# How to start application on Windows startup?

Tags: c++, windows, registry, startup

I'm creating C++ application and would like to give my users an option to start my application when starting windows. First thing to mind is that I use windows registry to set that, but don't know where to write and what to write. Also, do users need to have admin privileges when running my application so that it is able to write in that part of Windows registry where needed?

Comment: Did you mean that you wanted the application to start when Windows starts, or that you wanted the application to start when the user logs in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` key (see the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx%E2%80%8E) for additional information). The (string) value should be the path to your application.

You don't need administrative privileges to create it in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, but your application will only start for the current user's session. If you need to start up automatically for all the users, use the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` hive with elevated privileges!

Comment: Thanks. I think this will do it.

Answer (score 1):

The registry is the hidden way to do so; the Startup folder in the Programs menu is the user-visible way to do so. See `CSIDL_STARTUP`. No admin permissions needed, it's a per-user setting. Admin permissions would be required for `CSIDL_COMMON_STARTUP`.

Comment: But then it's harder to detect if the application is already in startup.

Comment: It's in fact quite a bit easier, just a file check.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the application to start up through registry.
I wrote a sample function for you

```
    public void AddToStartup(string name)
    {
        RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        rkApp.SetValue(name + ".exe", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. It's no problem for me to write the code. I just wanted to know where and what to write and does it need admin privilegues.